# Revit: Modifying is forbidden because the document has no open transaction

Tags: revit, revit-api, revitpythonshell

Modifying  is forbidden because the document has no open transaction.
The document has no open transaction.
In Revit Document.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this as `revitpythonshell`:

```
try:
    transaction = Transaction(doc, 'a name for your transaction)
    transaction.Start()
    do_stuff_that_needs_to_modify_document()
    transaction.Commit()
except:
    transaction.Rollback()
    throw_hands_up_in_the_air_and_cry_in_frustration()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. change the TransactionMode to Automatic at the class attribute

   [Transaction(TransactionMode.Automatic)]
2. open a transaction within your command

   Transaction tr = new Transaction(commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document);
   tr.Start("Command name here");

   // your code

   tr.Commit();

Comment: Remember to always put transactions in a using block, as demonstrated here: https://boostyourbim.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/use-a-using-block-with-transactions/ & http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/04/scope-and-dispose-transactions.html

Answer (score -1):

close streamreader function

```
Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream("baglanti.ini", FileMode.Open)
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fs)
    baglanti_kodu = sr.ReadLine()
    fs.Close()
    sr.Close()  <---- they
```