# Delete Maskined Region from Revit Document using C#

Tags: revit, revit-api

I want Delete Maskined Region from Revit Document using C#.
Error : Modifying  is forbidden because the document has no open transaction.
Exception: ModificationOutsideTransactionException

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

change the TransactionMode to Automatic at the class attribute

```
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Automatic)]
```

open a transaction within your command

```
Transaction tr = new Transaction(commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document);
tr.Start("Command name here");

// your code

tr.Commit();
```

Also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428726/revit-modifying-is-forbidden-because-the-document-has-no-open-transaction/31429221).